# Creating a list, preforming an operation, and overwriting in python

Tags: python, list, directory

I am trying to create a list of the files in Folder_A, Folder_B all the way to Folder_Z then perform operation "do this". I want to add  all the files from each folder to one list, file_list, preform the operation "do this" then reset the list as empty and move on to the next folder.

```
Run Code:
Folder_A files to folder_list, preform "do this"
empty folder_list
Folder_B files to folder_list, preform "do this"
empty folder_list
...
Folder_Z files to folder_list, preform "do this"
empty folder_list
```

How do I do this? Here is my current code:

```
folder_list = []
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(Path):                                                                                                                    
    for filename in fileList:                                                                                                                                                
        if "_Folder" in dirName:              
            if ".txt" in filename.lower():                        
                folder_list.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))
"do this"
```

This code adds all the files to the list from each folder so if Folder_A through Folder_Z each contain 3 files, my list populates to 78 files then performs the opperation "do this" instead of doing the first 3, resetting, then moving forward.

Comment: `folder_list = []` resets `folder_list` with an empty list

Answer (score 2):

You're redefining `folder_list` to `folder_list = []` everytime when `if ".txt" in filename.lower():` is `True`.

```
folder_list = []
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(Path):                                                                                                                    
    for filename in fileList:                                                                                                                                                
        if "_Folder" in dirName:              
            if ".txt" in filename.lower():
                folder_list.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))
"do this"
```

Comment: I editing my statement, hopefully that clears up what I am looking for @Peterwood